# Finding a permutation through its rank, cant understand the last step of the algorithm

Tags: combinatorics

We want to find $s$ permutation if given its rank (how many permutations are before it)

So supposedly we first have to express the rank through the sum of $n-1, n-2...$ factorials (Cantor's system i think its called), so if we have rank $j=53$ with $n=6$, with $n$ being the length of $s$, we proceed as:

$53 = 0 \times 5! + 2\times4! + 0\times3! + 2\times2! + 1\times1!$

For $α_i$ being the factors of the factorials we have:

$α_1 = 0, α_2=2, α_3=0, α_4=2, α_5=1, α_6=0$

And after that the book makes a key notice that i dont quite get:

"The $α_i$ sequence is the sequence of the inversions of $s$ with opposite order"

**What i know:**

The inversions of a permutation $p$ are, as i know it: how many numbers after a digit of $p$ are smaller than it. E.g for $p = 524$ the inversions are:

$p_1 = 0, p_2 = 1, p_3=0$

Also the rank formula is: $rank(p) = p_1\times(n-1)!+p_2\times(n-2)!+\dots+p_{n-1}\times1!$

**The problem:**

I dont understand the thought process of what he is doing after. He says:

> Since  $α_1 = 0$,  that  means  $s_1=1$.
>
> Since $α_2 = 2$,  that means  $s_1=4$.

And so on until he finds all digits of the permutation. What did he do, i really dont get it with the information i have.